# jQuery/Javascript function can't print/echo the return value into element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery function timer.

```js
(function( $ ){
$.fn.makeTimer = function(val){
    var val = val;

    setInterval(function() {
        var result;

        var startTime = new Date(val);
            startTime = (Date.parse(startTime) / 1000);

        var now = new Date();
            now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

        var timePassed = now - startTime;

        var years = Math.floor(timePassed / (86400 * 365));
        var months = Math.floor((timePassed / (86400 * 30.41)) - (years * 12));
        var days = Math.floor((timePassed / 86400) - (years * 365) - (months * 30.41));
        var hours = Math.floor( (timePassed / 3600 )  - (years * (24 * 365)) - (months * (24 * 30.41)) - (days * 24) ) ;
        var minutes = Math.floor( (timePassed / 60) - ( years * (1440 * 365) ) - (months * (1440 * 30.41)) - (days * (60 * 24)) - (hours * 60 ) );
        var seconds = Math.floor(timePassed - (years * (86400 * 365)) - (months * (86400 * 30.41)) - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60) );

        if (months < "10") { months = "0" + months; }
        if (days < "10") { days = "0" + days; }
        if (hours < "10") { hours = "0" + hours; }
        if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
        if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "0" + seconds; }
        console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
        result = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        return result;
    }, 1000);
};
})( jQuery );

$("#timers").makeTimer("07 April 2022 13:00:00 GMT+07:00");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timers"></div>
```

And I call like this,

```
$("#timers").makeTimer("07 April 2022 13:00:00 GMT+07:00");
```

This is the HTML element,

```
<div id="timers"></div>
```

After tried to run the code, I can't print/echo the text into `$("#timers")`, but when I try to `console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);` I can see the value.

What I want, how to return result correctly into `this` element?

Comment: Returning from an `setInterval` callback, doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add at the top of your function:

```js
var $element = this;
```

Then, after calculating `results`:

```js
$element.text(result)
```

If you need all the values:

```js
$element.append(`<br />${result}`)
```

```js
(function( $ ){
$.fn.makeTimer = function(val){
    var val = val;
    var $element = this;

    setInterval(function() {
        var result;

        var startTime = new Date(val);
            startTime = (Date.parse(startTime) / 1000);

        var now = new Date();
            now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

        var timePassed = now - startTime;

        var years = Math.floor(timePassed / (86400 * 365));
        var months = Math.floor((timePassed / (86400 * 30.41)) - (years * 12));
        var days = Math.floor((timePassed / 86400) - (years * 365) - (months * 30.41));
        var hours = Math.floor( (timePassed / 3600 )  - (years * (24 * 365)) - (months * (24 * 30.41)) - (days * 24) ) ;
        var minutes = Math.floor( (timePassed / 60) - ( years * (1440 * 365) ) - (months * (1440 * 30.41)) - (days * (60 * 24)) - (hours * 60 ) );
        var seconds = Math.floor(timePassed - (years * (86400 * 365)) - (months * (86400 * 30.41)) - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60) );

        if (months < "10") { months = "0" + months; }
        if (days < "10") { days = "0" + days; }
        if (hours < "10") { hours = "0" + hours; }
        if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
        if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "0" + seconds; }
        console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
        result = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        $element.text(result);

        return result;
    }, 1000);
};
})( jQuery );

$("#timers").makeTimer("07 April 2022 13:00:00 GMT+07:00");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timers"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, the element id `timers` can be with another name.  So how can We set return value from function into another id `timers`. ex: `#timers2, #timers10, #timers12, #timers30, etc

Comment: ohhh I see what you need, I updated my answer, the gist, `this` is the element that called the function, so you need to save the reference, is the same as your `val` variable